# Programmatic authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security in my application.

I have all the pages secured. But couple of URL needs to be available both for system user and anonymous user.

But anonymous user should not have direct access to the URLs. He gets a link with unique token and gets access to some URLS if this token is valid.
What I want to do is:

1. In controller check if token in URL is valid
2. If it is - authenticate user in the system programmatically using some predefined login and password. This user will be configured to have authority to access necessary URLs.

The question is:
Is this a correct approach to perform user authentication programatically with some roles in controller if token is valid? Is this safe approach?

Comment: Why do you need this token malarky in the first place? Regardless, the "proper" spring-security way would be to implement this in a custom `AuthenticationProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Security is an aspect. An aspect can be decoupled from your main code (controller) to reduce code duplication and improve flexibility. Move authentication code from controller to new filter (be sure that this filter executed after spring security filter chain). You will be able secure new URLs via web.xml (zero lines of code).

Comment: Even better, use the intended extension points in Spring-security, i.e. a custom `AuthenticationProvider`, to reduce the fragmentation and complexity.

Comment: I am not sure. Even Spring Security itself does not do it (see [AnonymousAuthenticationFilter#doFilter](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java))

Comment: AnonumousAuthenticationFilter implements the `javax.servlet.Filter`, but it's not primarily intended to be used as a generic servlet filter, it's intended to be used in the spring-security custom authentication filter stack. That is another extension-point you can use to inject your own, custom authentication scheme in spring-security. Why they chose to muddle the architecture by mixing concerns (servlet-filter signature and custom spring-security filter), I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way to do this is:

- move the shared operations into service layer
- define a controller for those anonymous user and make its authority
  as anonymous
- check the validity of token in this controller
- if valid, call some services method to perform the operations.
- render the result in this controller

Comment: Yes, I am doing like this right now.
But what if this contains UI controls which perform Ajax requests to server? Add token to each ajax request? Seems to be ugly approach...

Comment: No matter what method you adopt to send request back to server, you need to pass some parameters. The token is just one of them. So I don't think it's different when the request happens to be an Ajax one.